# What is the transformation matrix?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have the following problem:

"In $\mathbb{R^2}$ a basis is given $a=(a_1,a_2)$ where:

$a_1=(1,-1)$

$a_2=(0,1)$

For $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ it is known:

$f(a_1)=-6\cdot a_1$

$f(a_2)=1\cdot a_2$

Determine the matrix of transformation with regards to the standard e-basis."

My own answer would be this:

$$eF_e= \left(\begin{matrix}-6&0\\6&1\end{matrix}\right) $$

Which to me is very simple, since you just multiply the basis vectors with the constants and insert.

However, it turns out the solution to this problem is actually:

$$ eF_e= \left(\begin{matrix}-6&0\\7&1\end{matrix}\right) $$

Can anyone explain to me why this is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $e_1 = a_1 + a_2$, while $e_2 = a_2$. Hence $f(e_1) = f(a_1) + f(a_2) = -6a_1 + a_2 = (-6, 7)$, while $f(e_2) = f(a_2) = a_2 = (0, 1)$ By putting these vectors as first and second column of the matrix respectively, you get the right answer.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: @Carl Basically, what you had is the matrix that describes how to take a vector expressed in the basis $a$, apply $f$, and then express the answer in the basis $e$.